# iOS simple array predicate

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

My app utilizes core data. I have data source (NSMutableArray) loaded with core data records.
To filter the records, I'm using textfield ([JSTokenField](https://github.com/FivesquareSoftware/JSTokenField)) that has UITextField delegate in it's .m file.

When I'm filtering my search results, I'm using a simple predicate:

```
-(void)textFieldChanged
{
    NSString *fieldText =_toField.textField.text;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cLastName contains[cd] %@",fieldText];
    NSArray *testArr = [coreDataSource filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; //coreDataSource is my MutableArray with all core data records
    NSLog(@"%@",predicate);
    NSLog(@"Testarr %@",testArr);
}
```

NSLog returns empty array :

```
2013-11-05 20:53:36.765 MyApp[3045:60b] cLastName CONTAINS[cd] "​a"
2013-11-05 20:53:36.766 Myapp[3045:60b] Testarr (
)
```

However, when I change(hard code) my predicate string like this:
**NSString *fieldText = @"a";** in my code, I get valid results.

```
2013-11-05 21:00:34.917 MyApp[3054:60b] cLastName CONTAINS[cd] "a"
2013-11-05 21:00:34.929 MyApp[3054:60b] Testarr (
 "<MyUser: 0x1566fed0> (entity: MyUser; id: 0x156dbc30 <x-coredata://33798AE4-9768-4A2F-A0E8-C094F32972AD/MyUser/p5565> ; data: {\n    activities = \"<relationship fault: 0x1551c540 'activities'>\";\n etc...
```

I'm really lost, as why doesn't it work with subclassed textfield...

btw, coreDataSource array is array of custom objects, with various properties (cLastName is one of them)

Comment: why _toField.textField.text? should be _toField.text

Comment: well _toField is class that has several properties in it. Label, textfield, etc.. So I have to access it's textfield property. You can check it out here
https://github.com/FivesquareSoftware/JSTokenField/blob/master/JSTokenField/JSTokenField.h

Comment: have you tried using SELF.cLastName?

Comment: Hm, I'm not really sure, what do you mean. Use it in my predicate? Or where?

Comment: in your predicate try, [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.cLastName contains[cd] %@",fieldText];

Comment: I just tried it, but that sadly doesn't change anything :(

Comment: I have bad feeling about that JSTokenField class, and way I notify my class about textfield changes. Problem is, I can't use textfield delegate, because that class has it's own delegate, so I use local notifications

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldChanged) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

Comment: @Yanchi: Can you show the output of `[fieldText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, to check was is really in the string?

Comment: Martin, I think you are going right directon... I've got this 2013-11-05 21:24:52.186 MyApp[3086:60b] <e2808b41>

Comment: change it according to martin's code it will five you the data, your code at current stage is not converting it to the correct data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in a comment, `fieldText` converted to UTF-8 is `e2 80 8b 41`.

UTF-8 `e2 80 8b` is Unicode `U+200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE)`.

I cannot tell you where that special space character comes from, but if it occurs
only at the start or the end of the string, you could get rid of it with

```
fieldText = [fieldText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, it's good answer, I'm going to accept it, however problem still remains... string "Abc" gets converted to <e2808b41 6263> so I probably have to use different class than JSTokenField.

Comment: @Yanchi: The above code *should* work even with `<e2808b41 6263>`.

Comment: NSString *fieldText =_toField.textField.text;
NSLog(@"Before %@",[fieldText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

[fieldText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"After %@",[fieldText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

Comment: Sorry for messy input... I tried it, however, it gives me same result... Maybe I'm doing something wrong :)

Comment: @Yanchi: Do you *assign* the trimmed result to `fieldText`? Your code looks different from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Now it returns <41> (which is ascii value for A and that's exactly what I have there)

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to int and then get ascii value of that int to string :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40594/discussion-between-martin-r-and-yanchi)